# Data is returned to browser but Kendo Grid isn't called?

Tags: kendo-grid, asp.net-web-api2

I have a page that uses a number of Kendo grids. Each grid defines a data source, that makes an ajax call to a Wep API 2.0 resource.

Fiddler shows that the ajax call is being made and the data is being returned correctly. However, the grid appears to do nothing with it.  I have a function for the dataBound property on the grid and it is never called.

Any ideas what might be going on?

### UPDATE

Here is code and returned data.

### Data Source

```
var getUnassignedCases = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: hostUrl + "/api/cases/getUnassignedCases/" + sakUser,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            data: { id: sakCase }
        },
        scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        resizable: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: "single",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false,
            buttonCount: 10
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "SakCase",
            fields: {
                SakCase: { type: "number" },
                CaseId: { type: "string" },
                SakIntake: { type: "string" },
                CaseTypeDescription: { type: "string" },
                DateCreated: { type: "date" },
                CaseStatusCode: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10
});
```

### Grid

The `DisplayNoResultsFound` function is never called (as it stands now), so I didn't include the source.

```
$("#UnassignedCasesGrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
                { field: "CaseId", title: "Case ID", width: 150, template: "<a href='/Arms/Case_Information.aspx?SakCase=${SakCase}'>${CaseId}</a>" },
                { field: "SakIntake", title: "Intake ID", template: "#if (SakIntake === null) {# #} else {#<a href='/Arms/Intake.aspx?SakIntake=${SakIntake}'>${SakIntake}</a>#} #" },
                { field: "CaseTypeDescription", title: "Case Type", width: 100 },
                { field: "DateCreated", title: "Date Created", format: '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}', width: 100, editor: dateTimeEditor },
                { field: "CaseStatusCode", title: "Case Status" }
    ],
    dataSource: getUnassignedCases,
    dataBound: function () {
        DisplayNoResultsFound($('#UnassignedCasesGrid'), 'UnassignedCasesCount', 'Unassigned Cases');
    },
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    groupable: false,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    resizable: true,
    sortable: {
        mode: "single",
        allowUnsort: true
    },
    pageable: {
        buttonCount: 10
    }
});
```

### Return from Web API call

The first few fields. The length in the header reflects that 100 test rows where returned.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 17:46:56 GMT
Content-Length: 14993

[
  {
    "SakCase": 1,
    "CaseId": "2015M00001",
    "SakIntake": null,
    "CaseTypeDescription": "Medical Review",
    "DateCreated": "2014-08-04T17:19:59",
    "CaseStatusCode": "O"
  },
  {
    "SakCase": 2,
    "CaseId": "2015M00002",
    "SakIntake": null,
    "CaseTypeDescription": "Medical Review",
    "DateCreated": "2013-03-20T08:02:46",
    "CaseStatusCode": "O"
  }
]
```

### DOM after Call

Below was taken from chrome inspect element.

This is the definition of the columns:

```
<thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
    <th role="columnheader" data-field="CaseId" data-title="Case ID" class="k-header" data-role="sorter">
        <a class="k-link" href="#">Case ID</a>
    </th>
    <th role="columnheader" data-field="SakIntake" data-title="Intake ID" class="k-header" data-role="sorter">
        <a class="k-link" href="#">Intake ID</a>
    </th>
    <th role="columnheader" data-field="CaseTypeDescription" data-title="Case Type" class="k-header" data-role="sorter">
        <a class="k-link" href="#">Case Type</a>
    </th>
    <th role="columnheader" data-field="DateCreated" data-title="Date Created" class="k-header" data-role="sorter">
        <a class="k-link" href="#">Date Created</a>
    </th>
    <th role="columnheader" data-field="CaseStatusCode" data-title="Case Status" class="k-header" data-role="sorter">
        <a class="k-link" href="#">Case Status</a>
    </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This is the content of the table:

```
<table role="grid">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:150px">
        <col>
        <col style="width:100px">
        <col style="width:100px">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody role="rowgroup"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console of the browser at all? If the data is being pushed back to the browser then I suspect something is going wrong with binding the data to the grid (usually down to a custom template) do you have an example that will help assist you with this issue?

Comment: And there are NO errors at all. Also, the grid/template is working in some cases. Mainly if IE is used and the data type is changed to json. However, we are testing a new server and even that doesn't work (but it still works in dev environment).

Comment: Have you tried taking the templates out that you have on the columns just to make sure they are not interfering with the rendering of the grid data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a red herring. The browser wasn't getting the data and this wasn't a binding issue. We did test out our templates (which were fine) and we took the data being returned from the API and just plugged it explicitly into to the page and that worked great.

It turns out that when using Fiddler with a https connection, fiddler gets the data back, but then the browser rejected it due to CORS configuration.  This was seen in the console of the browser developer tools once I put in some messages to try and figure out where the binding issue was (so I then opened the console).  Once the API server was configured to allows cross site access using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the web.config file, it worked.